# Bucle NO se ejecuta

Tags: java, while, try-catch

No se me ejecuta bien un do while y no sé por qué, cuando quito el try catch, funciona perfectamente, pero con el try catch NO.

```
int num=0;
boolean error=true;

do {
  try {
    System.out.print("Introduce un múltiplo de Cinco: ");/*pedimos el número*/
    num = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());  /*lo almacenamos en num*/
    error=false;
  }
  catch (Exception er) {
    System.out.println("ERROR!, introduzca un múltiplo de Cinco: ");
  }
} while (num%5!=0 && error==true);
```

Comment: bueno si ese es el caso solo modifica el while con !=0 por que la verdad no dijiste que es lo que querías que realizara tu programa y si quieres validar que el dato ingresado sea un numero mediante try y catch solo utiliza la exception `InputMismatchException` catch(InputMismatchException e) { System.out.println("ERROR!, introduzca un numero: "); }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVENTADO!!!
Basta con cambiar  del while el (5%!=0 || error==true)
Así garantizo la repetición del bucle mientras no sea múltiplo de 5 y da error si introduces letras.
Gracias Trauma por tu aporte.

Comment: Claro!! antes con el && debían de darse los dos condicionantes para que el bucle se repitiera y eso es erróneo, con ("or") con que uno de los dos condicionantes se cumpla, ya se repite, es decir, se va a repetir mientras NO sea múltiplo de 5 o bien mientras se produzca el error.

Answer (score -1):

hola lo que pasa es que no estas haciendo bien tu condición del `while`

```
while (num%5!=0 && error==true);
```

estas indicando que mientras un numero residual de 5 sea diferente de 0 osea lo contrario de un múltiplo  por que un múltiplo no deja residuo y ademas comparas tu variable `error` sea igual a `true` y antes lo haces false

```
error=false;
```

por lo que tu `while` siempre regresa un valor `false` y cuando un `while` regresa un valor `false` es el termino del ciclo. Entonces para ejecutar bien tendrías que cambiar tu `condicion` del `while` y listo te quedaría algo así

```
    int num=0;
    do {

        System.out.print("Introduce un múltiplo de Cinco: ");/*pedimos el número*/
        num = sc.nextInt(); //<-- aquí no hay necesidad de parsear si utilizas el scaner nextInt(); 


    } while (num%5==0);
      System.out.print("El numero :"+num+" \nno es un multiplo de 5");
```

Comment: Mi intención es que el bucle se repita mientras el residuo, sea distinto de cero, así garantizo que el número introducido es múltiplo de cinco. Como tu lo pones, NO se repite el bucle si introduces un 7, por ejemplo. Además de eso quiero usar el try catch para que si introduces letras, por ejemplo, imprima el error. No obstante; muchas gracias por tu aporte.